# zgrep in tar.gz and print the result

Tags: unix

I am trying to grep the files inside tar.gz.
tar.gz can have folders and files so I want to search through all and print the o/p like grep prints.
I tried following (file_path has many tar.gz archives)

```
zgrep -B 4 "Token to Search" /file_path/*
```

I am getting o/p as :

abc.tar.gz:Binary file (standard input) matches

I want lines that matches `zgrep` and also 4 lines before that matched line,

tar.gz can have /Folder1/file.log etc.
Is it possible to do such zgrep ?

Comment: Can you try with `zgrep -a`?

Comment: Do you mean it worked?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Yes. It did!!                                                                      
      zgrep -a -B 4 "Token to Search" /file_path/*

Comment: ok, I wasn't sure this is the correct answer so I posted a comment. I have it converted it to a real answer. Accept it if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `-a` option. In `man zgrep` it says:

> All options specified are passed directly to grep.

And in `man grep`:

```
   -a, --text

    Process a binary file as if it were text; this is equivalent to the
    --binary-files=text option.
```